# Generics: How to handle multiple bounded types in class hierarchy

Tags: java, generics

I have a repository which returns objects implementing two interfaces

```
public interface MyRepository<T extends A & B> extends JpaRepository<T, Long>
  List<T> findAll();
  ...
```

Using Spring I inject all implementations of these into another class, but additionally specifying that the generic type should itself additionally implement a certain interface `C`

```
class X {
  @Autowired
  private List<MyRepository<? extends C> myCRepos;
```

Note that C is an interface which does not extend A & B, but all the concrete implementations I want injected implement all three interfaces

```
class MyConcreteClass implements A, B, C
```

So a `public interface ConcreteRepo extends MyRepository<MyConcreteClass>`is correctly found by Spring and injected, as expected in the `List` of class `X`.

If I now use the `findAll`method, its return type is inferred by the IDE as `List<? extends C>`.

**Why is the return type not rather `List<? extends A & B & C>`?**

For testing I want to mock this `findAll`and so return an object of the correct type, but the following already fails:

```
List<? extends C> someTestList = new ArrayList<>();
someTestList.add(new MyConcreteClass()); // 
// has error like
// The method add(capture#1-of ? extends C) in the type 
// List<capture#1-of ? extends C> is not applicable for the arguments (C)
```

**How should I fix this error?**

Finally, I want to mock this whole thing

```
Mockito.when(myRepo.findAll()).thenReturn(someTestList);
```

Same question, what should be the type `someTestList`and how to create it?

Comment: does C extend A and B?

Comment: No. C is separate of A & B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more reading on generics, here's the solution. First, as noted by Philipp Wendler, the `someTestList` must be typed without a wildcard to be able to actually input something in it.

```
List<C> someTestList = new ArrayList<>();
someTestList.add(new MyConcreteClass()); //
```

Additionally, in the call to Mockito, the compiler needs a hint on the return type:

```
Mockito.<List<? extends C>>when(myRepo.findAll()).thenReturn(someTestList);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not certain about the answer to your first question, but the second question has nothing to do with your complex type hierarchy. Whenever you have a `List<? extends Something>`, you will not be able to add something to it, because this basically declares the list as a list of "some unknown type", and Java cannot ensure that `MyConcreteClass` is an instance of "some unknown type". You can solve this and your third question by declaring `someTestList` as `List<MyConcreteClass>`.